# Assign Null (missing) values on section access reduction

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Suppose I have the following very simple data warehouse:

```
section application;

car:
LOAD * INLINE
[
CAR,USER
GETZ,George
];

person:
LOAD * INLINE
[
USER
George
Maria
];
```

As you can see, USER George has a CAR GETZ, while USER Maria has no car.

Is it possible to set the section access up, using reduction field=CAR, so that
a user can only see Maria, who has a null value on CAR?

I have read COUNTLESS posts. Many say to put an empty string- that doesn't work. I have also seen multiple "Answers" having sample qvds attached - and most of them use a single table with an *empty string value* to make the test, which then seems to work with the *empty string value* at section access. Of course, this is not the case I'm interested, as the *empty string value* is still different than a *missing/nulul* value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because section access works via associations in Qlik it wouldn't be possible with your current data model. Maria doesn't have a null car - she has no car association (which will show as a null if you put USER and CAR in a table but it's a subtle difference). If structured your data a little differently you could potentially make it work with a blank... something like

```
car:
LOAD * INLINE
[
CAR,USER
GETZ,George
];

outer join(car):
LOAD * INLINE
[
USER
George
Maria
];
```

You might need to populate the null values with blank afterwards...

```
car2:
NOCONCATENATE LOAD
if(isnull(CAR),'',CAR) as CAR,
USER
Resident car;

drop table car;
```

If it's not possible to join the two tables then you could add blank entries to your car table?

```
car:
LOAD 
*,
USER as USER2 
INLINE
[
CAR,USER
GETZ,George
];

person:
LOAD * INLINE
[
USER
George
Maria
];

concatenate(car)
LOAD 
USER,
'' as CAR
RESIDENT person
WHERE NOT EXISTS (USER2,USER);
```

There are also options with some kind of combined key or applymaps potentially, but hopefully one of the above is helpful enough...

Comment: Your answer is generally towards adding a "dummy row" in the car table. I don't like this, it falsifies the data (eg: count(distinct CAR) for Maria should return 0, not 1). Is there no other way? Am I correct to think this is a major oversight?

Comment: It's not an oversight - it's to do with association - there is no value for CAR associated with Maria so you can't link on that data - whether for section access or just in the data model itself. 

What you're asking for is to be able to link to Maria based on a link that isn't in your data model - so you have to create that link somehow or find another way to do what you want.  

The first one I propose doesn't really fake any data - it doesn't add any rows - it just populates a table with null or blank for CAR by joining the tables. The second one does indeed make new rows though.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I still think it's an oversight. If the qlik engine is able to show null values in a chart table (and by extension show non-null results on null values by mean of an if(isnull(...)) function), it would be perfectly -and easily- possible to handle the null values without having to resort to manual joins in the script.